# Serializing JSON with configured serializer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am using ASP.Net Web API with JSON.Net to serialize.  I had to configure the serializer to handle ISO dates properly like this:

```
var iso = new IsoDateTimeConverter {
    DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK"
};

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
    .SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(iso);
```

This works fine when I am passing my objects down via the WebAPI.  My problem, however, is that I have another place where I want to explicitly call the serialization:

```
@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
```

In this case, it doesn't use the configuration I set up.  I am aware that I can pass the `iso` converter into the `SerializeObject` call, but I prefer to avoid this and get a hold of a configured serialzer for obvious reasons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to do JSON serialization yourself, you have to pass the settings you want explicitly. There's no way around it. The best I can think of if you want to reuse the same serializer settings is to do something like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.
    JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings)
```